# What happens internally if I overwrite the original variable with a reference?

Tags: php, variables, reference

What happens internally if I overwrite the original variable with a reference?
Meaning is this bad, does it cost extra time or resources?

```
<?php
function db(){
    global $db;
    if( empty($db)) $db = new PDO('sqlite:/tmp/default.db3');
    return &$db;
}

$db = db();
?>
```

Comment: You are *not* "overwriting" with a reference. Probably you can better formulate what you actually do not understand about return by reference?

Comment: using `global` in php  in 2012 - its bad practice.

Comment: Interesting question indeed. I think this is utter bad practice to do so. Just keep it theoretical. (I'm hardly ever reasoning with my upvotes but this was needed.)

Comment: Also your snippet is a syntax error, under php 5.4.5. You probably meant `$db =& ...`

Comment: That is invalid code, return by reference is done by decorating the function declaration like this: `function &some_function(){}`

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
global $db;
```

this will import the global variable `$db` into the local scope.

It then there exists as another variable (that represents the global variable). You finally *try* to return a reference to that variable:

```
return &$db;
```

But this is not [return by reference](http://de.php.net/manual/language.references.return.php). Instead you just return the value.

You then ovewrite on the global variable table the `$db` with it's own value. That's all what is happening here.

> does it cost extra time or resources?

Everything superfluous you do costs extra time or resources. However PHP has an optimization called copy on write (COW) so normally you do not need to care much here. PHP is pretty well to remove the burden.

As far as objects are concerned in your code. Just change it this way:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('sqlite:/tmp/default.db3');

?>
```

Then pass the db object where it is needed. Keep it simple, stupid.

Answer (score 0):

It should not consume any more resources, because you're returning the address of the object which is always smaller then the object.

If I was not mistaken, When an object is returned in PHP 5, it's returned by reference even if you don't prepend the (&) to it. (I stand corrected objects are not returned by referance):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

I know from all other programming languages that objects are returned by passed/returned by reference and native data types by copy.

In your example when you used the global variable, you have already referanced the variable outside the function. There is no need for the return value since you have already overriden it.

Comment: Which again is not correct. Objects are not returned by reference. You find that in the PHP manual here: [Objects and references](http://de.php.net/manual/language.oop5.references.php)

Comment: I said if I was not mistaken. I have just read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

Comment: No, objects are returned by value, always. However their value is an object identifier. So even if you copy the value, you only copy the identifier. You can not copy objects by value therefore practically (that is why some think it must be a reference, but it is not), you can only [clone](http://de.php.net/clone) them.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way you return by reference.
You must declare the function like this:

```
function &return_by_ref()
{
    $something="";
    return $something;
}
```

You need not return objects by reference, the language specifies all objects are returned by reference automatically, and the manual also strongly recommends not to use the by reference operator for objects.

Is this what u actually mean:

```
class DB{
   private function __construct(){}
   public static $db=null;
}

function db($db)
{
   if(!isset(DB::$db))
      DB::$db=new PDO('sqlite:/tmp/default.db3');
   return DB::$db;
}
```

Usage:

```
function create_user()
{
   db()->exec("INSERT INTO `users` SET `name`='John Doe'");
   return db()->lastInsertId();
}

function get_users()
{
   return db()
      ->query("SELECT * FROM `users`")
      ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
   ;
}
```

Comment: As Hakre rightly states, the documentation doesn't actually say that "language specifies all objects are returned by reference automatically". Whilst the effect is pretty similar if you try to modify the object variable within the function without a pass by reference you will not actually modify the object. (You'll just lose the reference and have a new variable) The value passed to the function is the identifier of the object, not a reference to the in-memory space the variable is located.

Comment: Do you have any proof of that? Are you aware there are multiple PHP implementations out there (Zend, HipHop, Phalanger)? Are you aware this is a likely optimisation, and if it doesn't exist yet, it certainly will in the future? Did you know that in an Exception's stack trace, an object appears in its last modified state for each and every function which added a different modification (making debugging a pain)?

Comment: Also, did you read my answer's first line? The question contains invalid PHP code. While that is the case, I cannot answer about the internals of PHP for invalid PHP code.

Comment: Also I gave an example which actually passes an object for each and every query, without storing the PDO object in a variable before use, which is way closer to the question, than the given example, not to mention correct and just as efficient as omitting the function return reference operator (which has no effect when returning objects).

Comment: From this http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php "One of the key-points of PHP 5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true. This section rectifies that general thought using some examples."

Comment: From your link: "It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.". Guess what, that identifier would always point to the same object which always takes the same memory space. Think about this: an object which holds active network connnection handles, or objects which have active network connections (such as PDO objects). Same memory space. Still the PHP in the question is wrong, so nothing about that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your original example is syntax error, i think this is what you wanted to write:

```
function db(){
    static $db = null;
    if ($db === null) {
        $db = new PDO('sqlite:/tmp/default.db3');
    }
    return $db;
}
```

If you are really that inclined, you can run your script with [vulcan logic disassembler](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld) and get the opcodes. The only notable difference is that the versions with references uses RETURN_BY_REF and ASSIGN_REF opcodes instead of RETURN and ASSIGN. It's not trivial to determine what the engine does when those executed, but mainly the copy-on-write behaviour usually prevents copying.